Missing CPU Scaling Governors
I bought a new computer very recently and installed Linux for the first time. My knowledge of this operating system is therefore very limited.
By chance I came across a page about CPU Scaling Governors. After reading the article, it seemed to me that the schedutil governor was the most appropriate because it's a good compromise between power and energy consumption. So I wanted to change the default governor to schedutil instead.
After some research, I saw that I might need to install cpufrequtils and sysfsutils, which I did with the commands:
$ sudo apt install cpufrequtils

$ sudo apt install sysfsutils

These utilities were installed correctly (Konsole did not report any problems).
The problem is that schedutil doesn't seem to be available on my computer, only powersave and performance seem to be available:
$cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
performance powersave

$ sudo modprobe cpufreq_schedutil
modprobe: FATAL: Module cpufreq_schedutil not found in directory /lib/modules/6.11.0-8-generic

$ echo schedutil | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Argument invalide

$ sudo sed -i 's/^GOVERNOR=.*/GOVERNOR="schedutil"/' /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils

Moreover, in the file /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils (before it was modified by the last command), the default governor was ondemand, whereas the console indicates that the performance governor is being applied.
Have I done something wrong?
The information about my system is as follows:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.10
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.6.2
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-8-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 32 × AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D 16-Core Processor
Memory: 30.4 Gio of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 7900 XTX
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7E16
System Version: 1.0


The available CPU frequency scaling governors is a function of the CPU frequency scaling driver being used. Do cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver to know. I am more familiar with the intel_pstate driver, but you are likely using the AMD driver. If you set its mode to passive, for the intel_pstate driver do echo passive | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status, for the AMD driver I don't know, then the schedutil CPU frequency scaling driver will become available.

@DougSmythies Thank you for your help. My driver is amd-pstate-epp. By analogy, I've tried echo passive | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/amd-pstate-epp/status, but the console gives me an error (no file or folder with that name).
I've looked for information about this driver, and strangely enough, in this link, it says that this driver can use schedutils.

There seems to be an amd_pstate=passive option, but I don't know if it has the same effect as with the Intel driver. I confess that this is beyond my knowledge.

have a look with ls -l /sys/devices/system/cpu to see if it has a slightly different name, like maybe amd_pstate. Anyway, active mode for these drivers are a mode where most of the scaling work is done in the processor itself.

Seems to be kernel specific. I have updated from 6.10 to 6.11 and now I have idle 550 MHz instead of 2.2 GHz. Also other frequencies disappeared. I only have performance powersave. Using Fedora 40.
